# allocating contigous seat in seat map

Tags: algorithm

I have to write an algorithm for Assigning Contiguous seats in a seat map.For example: allocating seats in a stadium. The seat map can be viewed as a 2d array of N rows and M columns. The system must assign contiguous seats for bookings that are made together. Since no seat map is presented to the user, the system should automatically assign the available seats corresponding to each purchase. In addition to this, it should do this in such a fashion such that the holes/gaps in the seats are minimized.

Comment: Does "I have to" mean that this is homework? Also, what's the question? And you have it tagged as both Java and C...they're quite different languages.

Comment: Do you know all the bookings in advance, or dou you receive them one by one and assign them on the fly?

Comment: Its not a howework but I am looking for an algorithm to solve this problem. The problem is that we have a seat map containing N rows and M columns. The seats should be assigned contiguously for bookings that are made together. This means that tif user ask for 3 seats then 3 seats should be contiguous. And this seat allocation should also be done in a fashion such that the holes or gaps in the seat map are minimized.

Comment: No, we dont know all the bookings in advance. We assign them one by one. Its similar to the case of booking theatre seats for a movie.The users come and asks for a number of seats and system allocates the seats to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding a perfect solution is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard). Look at the equivalent language problem: 

`L={((x1,x2,...,xk),n,m)}` where xi are the number of co-booked tickets, and n,m are the stadium sizes.

We will show [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) <=(P) L, and thus this problem is NP-Hard, and there is no known polynomial solution for it.

**Proof**

let `S=(x1,x2,..,xk)` be the input for a partition problem, and let `sum=x1+...+xk`

Look at the following reduction:

```
Input: S=(x1,...,xk)
Output:((x1,...,xk),sum/2,2)
```

**Correctness:**
If S has a partition, let it be `S1=(x_i1,x_i2,...,x_it)`, then by definition of partition, `x_i1+...+x_it=sum/2`, and thus we can insert `x_i1,..,x_it` in the first row, and the rest in the second row, and so `((x1,...,xk),sum/2,2)` is in L

If `((x1,...,xk),sum/2,2)` is in L, then by definition there are t bookings such that `x_i1,x_i2,...,x_it` form a perfect first line, and thus `x_i1+x_i2+...+x_it=sum/2`, and thus it is a valid partition and S is in Partition problem

**Conclusion:**

Since L is NP-Hard, and the problem you seek is the optimization problem for this language, there is no known polynomial solution for it. For an exact solution you can use [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) [check all possibilities, and choose the best], but it will take a lot of time, or you can sattle for a heuristic solution, such as [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), but it will not be optimized.

**EDIT:** Backtracking solution [pseudocode]:

```
solve(X,n,m):
   global bestVal <- infinity
   global bestSol <- null
   solve(X,new Solution(n,m))
solve(X,solution):
   if (X is empty):
       gaps <- solution.numGaps()
       if (gaps < bestVal):
            bestVal <- gaps
            bestSol <- solution
       return
   temp <- X.first
   X.removeFirst()
   for i from 0 to m:
       solution.addToLine(i,temp)
       solve(X,solution)
       solution.removeFromLine(i,temp)
   X.addFirst(temp)
```

Assuming `Solution` is an implemented class, and for an illegal solution [i.e. too many people in one row] `numGaps() == infinity`

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

This is usually not a real problem, because if you are able to sell all your tickets - the last buyers will either compromise and break their bookings into separate bookings, or withdraw, and allow other buyers with different booking-size requirements to buy the remaining seats.

Moreover, people like to select their seats. If you want to ban this option - they may select not to buy tickets at all.

Note that if the buyers have no control over their seats, you may as well given them a code, and translate this code into a specific seat once all the tickets are sold.

**Answer for the posed problem:**

Each row has *m* seats.  We will assume that the largest booking-size is *m* (otherwise, we'll have to break it into several bookings).

First, we should model the discrete probability distribution function for the booking-size. This can be constructed based on data from previous events. (A more advanced model may consider the event-type, event-time etc.). Let us call this function *f(b)*

It is trivial that the best strategy would be to fill rows from left to right (or from right to left), and not leaving empty gaps - which would only force more constrains.

Let us suppose that the stadium contains a single row. We can calculate the probability of filling the whole row, by enumerating all possible booking-sizes. We can use the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026751/how-many-ways-to-represent-a-number-from-a-given-set-of-numbers/8027687#8027687) for the enumeration, multiplying each bookings-size with its probability, and summing it up.

Now, assume that there are 2 rows in the stadium, and that the first booking-size was 3. Now there is a row with *m* empty seats, and another row with *m-3* empty seats. The second booking size is 4. Now we can compare the probability of filling a *(m-4)* seats row, and the probability filling a *(m-3-4)* seats row. We will assign seats for the current booking accordingly.

Of course, the probability of filling an empty row is 1, and once filled it should be removed from the non-filled rows list.

In general, for each booking, we can assign it to the row that the probability for filling it (after the assignment) would be maximized.

Note that given *f(b)*, all these probabilities can be calculated in advance for any constant between *1* and *m*.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at memory allocation algorithms for operating systems. This best models your problem. you should focus on algorithms that minimize fragmentation.

Answer (score -1):

I like that last one.  He's very correct in the simplest sense.  For speed, a probability map test is a great way to fill the rows. But it lacks a few elements.  Do you care if parties are split by a number of seats?  What about cancelations and refunds?  Look at the problem a little differently.  There are 3 possible states, not 2.  M empty seats, in R Rows, Each with 3 possible states:  Vacant, Filled, Cancelled, where Cancelled has an adjusted probability.  How do you handle that?  You can increase the probability of filling cancelations or refunds by setting them as a new row, all their own with N seats, with a probability of 1 for filling sets of 1 to N seats, and you can further increase the probability of filling all the seats by limiting the probable party size when N > 2 to a party size >2 but less than N.

Another way is to use a map.  To illustrate, create a spreadsheet of small squares about seatsized.  now highlight areas and bound them with outer box lines.  These are your rows and columns sections.  place a letter in each seatsquare to indicate that seats availability.  Now create a database that links to that file.  You can add a section where you define the numbers for seats in the row, and then identify a ticket number for the venue based on that, and you can run simple tests to fill the seats.  It will "Minimize" gaps, but probably won't eliminate them entirely.  If, like me, you work with showpeople\entertainers\musicians and venues, the mapping is key.  The main group I work with is small, and have a loyal but ever-changing following.  THey are a kids program, community outreach, and performance group all in one.  The problem I had was that many people wanted to sit with friends, etc.  SO I came up with the multiple-ticket\ROW\TABLE plan of attack.  How do you handle this?
For every division you make, you must make a provision in your programming.  Rows and columns are good to work with.  We'll start there.  With tables, place them into rows and columns, and you can cut them nicely.  It may not be perfect, but it does work, with a little adjustment for each sectional division you make.

Consider this...
number your seats from left to right simply.  Follow this pattern when actually assigning seats to a ticket:
For column a row a go left->right   (which fills the seats in a straight line)
           a row b go right->left   (now follow the math below)
do the same for each column (think of it like a carnegie hall venue, where each column has aisles on each side, and goes for several rows).  The math for each row in a column is fairly basic.  Take the total seats in the even rows for group bookings is: If partysize > remainingSeatsInRow mult seat#_in_row by -1 then add to the seat#_Normal=S (where S is the seat#_within_row), if S* -1>0, S*-1=S endif, so the venue fills up by group and by single, keeping parties together.  Now to throw you through a few more loops... ...Say you adjust pricing by every 15 rows or so, then the higher price areas may fill up slower, so you can add incentives but only for those areas, or adjust incentives for each area and by the # of tickets available in that area and so on.  Now add the ability to check other pricing areas for the remaining seats to accommodate a group (remember, they just have to be in the same area and they'll still be sitting together by proximity;  I would focus on column operations only to save time, but to each their own) and now you can even send a request out to fill empty seats in higher priced areas for lower price, just to fill the venue near showtime and keep people happy with their pals.  Now for selection... ...you can have people select their placement if there's available seating.  In a situation I'm building for, the venues change like the date, so I have to flex this algorithm for all it's muscle.  Basically, the performances are charity work, and the people are parents, friends, community members etc, that know the groups performing and know each other.  If they know where somebody is sitting, they'll want to be close.  Get the number of tickets they want, and show the areas with that many seats available by whatever set you want; you can even go by both row and column (to use your example of seat filling; carnegie has several sets of aisles that split a column between rows, so you can either change column, or just keep on truckin right on through; carnegie also has level seating and balconies--as young mister Simpson would say, "Aye Carumba!"; each venue has it's different design layouts, if yours change, you've got to make a plan for it in your databases and work from that; this model is flexible as it can be adjusted to several diagrams) anyway, to get it right: use the original test to go in a straight line here (you could have them select the column and row of their pals, then test the column, and then the adjacent columns for the same rows with seat#'s tested for proximity, use the math from the original proximity keeper above, if pals on left, test left column on right seat#'s, if pals on right, check right column on left seat#'s and even compare cancelations *discussed later*, the operands of the  original test just swap places or you can flip it around etc) if you Highlight areas where seats are open, and then get a number from them, then highlight only the areas left that have that many contiguous seats available (run the test on 2 or more rows if needed, again the same testing as above is implemented in the rows of a column), they'll most likely be sitting together if you did the above testing correctly, but at the worst, they'll be sitting in closest possible proximity (and how often does this test take place, eh?  You can offer it as an option with a special pricing for as long as you have the space to fill, but logically, you should put a cap on the partysize that this secondary placement will accomodate, and it will most likely fail more often as you get closer to your showtime.
Now comes the fun part, the gap cleanup.  Some people go stag or will probably arrive late due to being at work, or traffic, and want to catch a show or see their child put on a ridiculous rendition of peter pan.  If your free seat count in any particular row or column is 1 and their are no more seats surrounding it (which should happen if people cancel), or you have an entire group cancel, you need to put these back into the sorting hat.  THere are several ways.  You can create a large array of seats for each section and work from that, but it may be better to just open up a new list to hold small arrays of adjacent seating that can fill the seats in your main; alternatively, you can create a seating map text file, marking every seat as vacant, full, canceled, and store the pointers of canceled groups, then Test the mapping for cancelations after each cancelation, and create separate mappings for different group sizes that contain the the seat lists for each size.  You can name the maps with the VenueTitle_Cancel_GroupSize, and then code the test to check all maps where GroupSize is >= to your new group.   This makes finding your pals harder because you have a new test, but you can use the same pretests to line these up for scanning available seating and drawing it up:  Test if there are any cancelations, test the numbers of contiguous seats for each cancelation (how many in the new group? will they fit in a cancelation slot?  Offer them a discount on the remaining seats in the cancellation slot, then handle all that input)... ...This isn't exactly an algorithm, not even close, just a mental design for the problem with a ton of IF styled basic arithmetic tests that should run like lightning, but you can split those tests by separating the machines that run them, and wait for all processes to come back, then add the results together, etc, (old school multiserver querying of a remote file, database query software hosted by remote machines; with newer servers, you can run the test faster by tying them together in XSERVE, and setting up multihomed farms that handle the datase, with smaller units handling your web front).

Planning:
   Figure out how to divide up your venue (s), then figure out how to number\count the different sections\seats and how to price tickets, and then figure out if you want people to pick their price with an interactive view, or a simplistic one.  WIth more interaction, you may end up with a few gaps.  If there are a few of these, you can have price drops or special invitations to interested parties etc with the listings for the seats.  This allows you to build in maximization of the venue, and offer choices that maximize satisfaction.  Not sure what that algorithm is called, but using a bubble sort, a database, or anything similar can allow you to set your values for ticketing, and all the information necessary from booking.  This allows you to process a cancelation as a separate but LINKED item, set flags, and repetetively add data handling to your operations that prevents over- or under-booking.  The basic way to do this: if you overbook, you get the timing tags of each of the last transactions, N+1 ( where N is the number of overbooked transactions), and everybody after the last booking (that filled the venue or just under) will be set asside into a new table with the same info on the transactions, then they will get checked for whether or not they still fit, and if not, they will get refunded, and emailed and or phonecalled.  That way, you can check the number of seats available and see if anybody wants to shorten their party.  You can also make new offers to them by exporting their info to a new table for CMS, and keep them happy.  It's a lot of work, but this method can run several concurrent tests if set up and processed properly.
This is probably a long winded and boring answer, but the credit goes to Lior who has a commonly used test stated.  This is just my long-program for maximization if you have the processing power and the time to build the code.